# How do I create a time plot in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a scatter plot in SAS. I used the following code below;

```
proc sgplot data = data1;
series y = data_points x = Date;
run;
```

However the code creates a scatter plot where the data_points are linked together by a line.

I do not want the data_points to be linked together at all.

How do I solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

- SERIES -> draws a line plot
- SCATTER -> draws a scatter plot

Change SERIES to SCATTER, that's the only change you need.